# Need google apps script to iterate through an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have modified this code I found but i cannot figure out how to get it to run for the whole spreadsheet.

the modified code copies a spreadsheet, renames it based on another spreadsheet and then files the document in the appropriate folder.

```
function generateMonthlyReport() {

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(CUSTOMER_SPREADSHEET);

  // Fetch variable names
  // they are column names in the spreadsheet
  var sheet = data.getSheets()[0];
  var columns = getRowAsArray(sheet, 1);

  Logger.log("Processing columns:" + columns);

  var customerData = getRowAsArray(sheet, CUSTOMER_ID);  
  Logger.log("Processing data:" + customerData);

  // Assume first column holds the name of the customer
  var customerName = customerData[1];
  var customerCityState = customerData[2];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  var target = createDuplicateDocument(SOURCE_TEMPLATE, "CSMR - " + customerName + ", " + customerCityState );
  Logger.log("Created new document"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure I understood exactly what you wanted to get as a final result but here is how the loop could be built, it will create a doc for each row of data.

```
function generateMonthlyReport() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Fetch variable names
  // they are column names in the spreadsheet
  var sheet = data.getSheets()[0];
  var columns = getRowAsArray(sheet, 1);
  for(var customer=2;customer<sheet.getLastRow();customer++){
    Logger.log("Processing row:" + customer);
    var customerData = getRowAsArray(sheet, customer);  
    Logger.log("Processing data:" + customerData);
    // Assume first column holds the name of the customer
    var customerName = customerData[0];
    var customerCityState = customerData[2];
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
    //  var target = createDuplicateDocument(SOURCE_TEMPLATE, "CSMR - " + customerName + ", " + customerCityState );
    Logger.log("Created new document for customer "+customer+' ctitle = CSMR - ' + customerName + ', ' + customerCityState); 
  }
}

function getRowAsArray(sheet, n){
  var array = [];
  var data = sheet.getRange(n,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for(var c=0;c<data[0].length;c++){
    array.push(data[0][c]);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Logger of the test + test sheet below :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I am trying to duplicate a template document for all of our customers with their info in the document title .. The system would not let me post the entire code .. This is what I need, now i just need some help getting this to duplicate a a spreadsheet and file it in s specific folder. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you should post another question about how to duplicate a spreadsheet in a specific folder... this way the post would be more clear and the answer more "question related on a narrow subject". Thx for accepting this one ;).

Comment: Nevermind.. i figured out the rest thank you for your help. :)